# Number Puzzle Coding

Tags: java, swing

I'm coding the Number Puzzle Game. I have 9 buttons, all of them are contained in a frame. My idea is: when pressing a button, it will check all buttons around it. If has an invisible button, that invisible one will become visible with the number from the pressed button, and the pressed one will become invisible. Here it's what i have:

```
 private void Btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    if (!Btn2.isVisible()) {
        Btn2.setText(Btn1.getText());
        Btn2.setVisible(true);
        Btn1.setVisible(false);
    } else if (!Btn4.isVisible()) {
        Btn4.setVisible(true);
        Btn4.setVisible(false);
        Btn1.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

private void Btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if (!Btn3.isVisible()) {
        Btn3.setText(Btn2.getText());
        Btn2.setVisible(false);
        Btn3.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!Btn1.isVisible()) {
        Btn1.setText(Btn2.getText());
        Btn1.setVisible(true);
        Btn2.setVisible(false);
    } else if (!Btn5.isVisible()) {
        Btn5.setText(Btn2.getText());
        Btn5.setVisible(true);
        Btn2.setVisible(false);
    } 
}                                    

private void Btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    if (!Btn2.isVisible()) {
        Btn2.setText(Btn3.getText());
        Btn3.setVisible(false);
        Btn2.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!Btn6.isVisible()) {
        Btn6.setText(Btn3.getText());
        Btn3.setVisible(false);
        Btn6.setVisible(true);
    }
}

 private void Btn4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn1.isVisible()) {
        Btn1.setText(Btn4.getText());
        Btn1.setVisible(true);
        Btn4.setVisible(false);
    } else if (!Btn5.isVisible()) {
        Btn5.setText(Btn4.getText());
        Btn5.setVisible(true);
        Btn4.setVisible(false);
    } else if (!Btn7.isVisible()) {
        Btn7.setText(Btn4.getText());
        Btn7.setVisible(true);
        Btn4.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

private void Btn5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn2.isVisible()) {
        Btn2.setText(Btn5.getText());
        Btn2.setVisible(true);
        Btn5.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn4.isVisible()) {
        Btn4.setText(Btn5.getText());
        Btn4.setVisible(true);
         Btn5.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn6.isVisible()) {
        Btn6.setText(Btn5.getText());
        Btn6.setVisible(true);
         Btn5.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn8.isVisible()) {
        Btn8.setText(Btn5.getText());
        Btn8.setVisible(true);
         Btn5.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

  private void Btn6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn3.isVisible()) {
        Btn3.setText(Btn6.getText());
        Btn3.setVisible(true);
        Btn6.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn5.isVisible()) {
        Btn5.setText(Btn6.getText());
        Btn5.setVisible(true);
        Btn6.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn9.isVisible()) {
        Btn9.setText(Btn6.getText());
        Btn9.setVisible(true);
        Btn6.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

private void Btn7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn4.isVisible()) {
        Btn4.setText(Btn7.getText());
        Btn4.setVisible(true);
        Btn7.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn8.isVisible()) {
        Btn8.setText(Btn7.getText());
        Btn8.setVisible(true);
        Btn8.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

  private void Btn8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn7.isVisible()) {
        Btn7.setText(Btn8.getText());
        Btn7.setVisible(true);
        Btn8.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn5.isVisible()) {
        Btn5.setText(Btn8.getText());
        Btn5.setVisible(true);
        Btn8.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn9.isVisible()) {
        Btn9.setText(Btn8.getText());
        Btn9.setVisible(true);
        Btn8.setVisible(false);
    }
}                                    

private void Btn9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!Btn6.isVisible()) {
        Btn6.setText(Btn9.getText());
        Btn6.setVisible(true);
        Btn9.setVisible(false);
    }else if (!Btn8.isVisible()) {
        Btn8.setText(Btn9.getText());
        Btn8.setVisible(true);
        Btn9.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

It seems very long and inefficient. How can I make it shorter ?

Comment: Is this code working as expected?

Comment: Generally speaking, numbered variables are always bad. Use an array or list instead

Comment: You would keep a collection of the various buttons and calculate adjacency (whether via a Graph-type collection or some basic index math)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, it works normal

Comment: If you want to have code reviewed, then see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Remove the GUI from the question, what you need is some kind of model which manages the state, it should be capable of taking a single cell (x/y) and determining what's around it and from that trigger actions - this a basic concept of MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void BtnAction(Button pressed, Button... neighbors) {
    for (Button neighbor : neighbors) {
        if (!neighbor.isVisible()) {
            neighbor.setText(pressed.getText());
            neighbor.setVisible(true);
            pressed.setVisible(false);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void Btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    BtnAction(Btn1, Btn2, Btn4);
}

private void Btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    BtnAction(Btn2, Btn3, Btn1, Btn5);
}

private void Btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    BtnAction(Btn3, Btn2, Btn6);
}

// and so on...
```